# How to use function in one class in another

Tags: php, oop

im newbie in OOP. I have file database.php

```
class Database{
    function db_row($con,$stuff,$table,$statements){
        return mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT {$stuff} FROM `{$table}` {$statements}"));
    }}
```

and i have file player.php

```
class Player{
    function get_id($con,$token){
    }}
```

And i want to use function db_row-class Database(file database.php) in the class Player(file player.php)

How can i do this?

Comment: By creating an object of class `Database` and executing the method `db_row()` on it. That is how OOP works. I suggest you read some beginners guide. That will give you a lot of insight into all the concepts you have to learn anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this below. Basically, you instantiate the `Database` object in `Player`'s constructor, then you can access the methods in `Database` inside `Player` as shown below.

```
<?php

    class Database{
        function db_row($con,$stuff,$table,$statements){
            echo "Success";
            //return mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT {$stuff} FROM `{$table}` {$statements}"));
    }}

    class Player {
        var $db;

        function __construct() {
             $this->db = new Database();
        }

        function get_id($con,$token){
            $this->db->db_row(null, null, null, null);
        }
    }

    $player = new Player();
    $player->get_id(null, null);

?>
```